# method for getting correct system path on windows

Tags: libevent, boost-filesystem

I have made up a  simple http server using libevent. The way the resource (folders in my case) are accessed is

```
http://serverAddress:port/path/to/resouce/
```

the path to resource is extracted using the decoded url . It works fine on Linux as request would be something like this

```
http://severAddress:port/home/vickey/folder
```

but on window$ request is

```
http://serverAddress:port/c:/users/vickey/folder
```

which results in decoded url as */c:/users/vickey/folder*. Its manually possible to remove the leading slash to correct the problem. However since I m using and learning boost libraries in my code I was wondering if there was some implementation of this sort ?  I tried using native() and relative_path(). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its definitely possible to do as you're asking, but I would suggest a different approach. How about creating a configuration property for the server which could be called RESOURCE_BASE_PATH. The resource path received in the URL would be appended to the RESOURCE_BASE_PATH to create the complete path.

This is pretty standard for FTP and HTTP servers and the like. On Windows, it could be set to "c:" and on Linux, left blank which would default to "/".

Also remember on Windows the slashes (\) are different than those on Unix (/).